# waiting animation while fetching data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a gif with a loading animation.
in my code I use `mysqli_query()` to fetch data from a server.
Because, the table is very large it takes time until I see the results.

I am trying to show a "loading" animation while the PHP function is fetching data.

This is my PHP code,

```
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = $_GET['variable'];

    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select q1.variable, t3.label, q1.numvalue, description, num_cases from (select variable, numvalue, count(variable) as num_cases from nhws.num_all_{$_SESSION['country']} where variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}' group by variable, numvalue) q1 inner join (select * from nhws.luvalues where source = '{$_SESSION['country']}' and variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}') t2 on q1.numvalue=t2.numvalue inner join (select * from nhws.luvariables where source = '{$_SESSION['country']}' and variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}') t3 on q1.variable=t3.variable;");
    echo "<h5>Counts</h5>";
    echo '<div id="container" ><img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Searching" /></div>';
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table><tr><th>Variable</th><th>label</th><th>Numvalue</th><th>Description</th><th>Num Cases</th></tr>";
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["variable"]. "</td><td>" . $row["label"]. "</td><td>" . $row["numvalue"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"]. "</td><td>" . $row["num_cases"]. "</td></tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";
    } else {echo "0 results";}
}
```

I am assuming that the function `mysqli_query()` is the one that takes time because, in my browser it says in the bottom right "waiting for (IP address of the server)"

I tried several methods with AJAX but it did not work while the website was waiting for the server. It did work when the website was waiting for itself and not for a query.

This is my script,

```
<script>
function makeLoadingGifDisappear() {
 document.getElementById('myLoadingGif').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

And this my HTML code which I replaced before my PHP code,

```
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="myLoadingGif">
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot cause a client-side action with a server-side function. You will need to use AJAX to accomplish what you're trying to do. Can you share the AJAX methods you tried? jQuery has several built-in functions that make this kind of thing very easy.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I edit my question and included my script

Comment: What calls `makeLoadingGifDisappear()`?

Comment: My bad! this is, `<body onload="makeLoadingGifDisappear()">` I included it in the body to show every time it thinks.

Comment: If you call it like that it will close immediately. You have to call it when the PHP returns your data.

Comment: So, where should I put it? before the `mysqli_query()` and in how? in a div?

Comment: I would call it at as part of `window.onload`.

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer? so, i will be able to follow your mind set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did to solve this problem is to hide the GIF with `<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="myLoadingGif" style= "display: none;">`

And where the user needs to pick and send the variable to make the query run I added `onchange='showDiv()'`

Which activates the function below,

```
function showDiv(){

      document.getElementById('myLoadingGif').style.display = "block";
}
```

And after the query finishes to run the GIF automatically switched to `display: none;` which is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a check in a `while` loop which will check `(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)` which means that if table has returned any data back. But, use an `if statement` inside loop so that you don't put loader everytime loop runs. Once you get back the data the `loop` going to quit and you can proceed with data.
:D

Comment: Changed it to mysqli. sorry, i forgot to put i

Answer (score 0):

Place the animated image tag in a `div` positioned with CSS to cover the portion of the screen you wish to cover and make sure it is the first thing loaded into the page body:

```
<div class="animated">
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="myLoadingGif">
</div>
```

You can now hide the animated `div` when the page finishes loading by adding the following just before the closing body tag (shown for reference):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('animated').style.display = 'none';
};
</script>
</body
```

Comment: But, that means that the GIF will always be there and I need it to run only with the query is executing. which means once `$_GET['variable']` is set and entering the IF statement.

Comment: That is exactly what you asked for. If you're not sending an AJAX request for the query your options are *very* limited. Since you tagged with jQuery you might want to look at the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` functions [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) as, IMHO, this would be a better way to do things. It requires that you setup a separate PHP file to call and that you call the AJAX function once the page loads - so the code may be a bit more complex.